# How to wrap C++ boost::variant in C++/CLI to grant access from .NET

Tags: c++-cli, boost-variant

I am wrapping a C++ library to C++/CLI to call the functionality from .Net. The C++ library has a type `using command = boost::variant<assignment, identifier, decimal>` and wonder how to wrap it.

I searched the web but couldnt find anything. And idea is appreciated.

Comment: There is no practical way to map .NET generics onto C++ templates.  Templates require all type arguments to be known at link-time, .NET generics are instantiated at runtime.  You'd have to fumble an enum type in the wrapper's public interface to force the wrapper user to limit himself to the type parameters you are willing to support.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, I did solve the issue like this: For each variant type I have created a managed type and added an appropriate marshal_as function. My variant visitor then converts the native type inside the variant into its managed counterpart. Then I return the managed type as an System::Object handle. 
The good thing is that it works fine, the bad is that I always have to do typechecks on the managed side...
I also thought about your enum idea and I do not see an advantage to use them. Can you please elaborate that?